# sencha app generate not working as documented

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

i executed following command for creating a sample app in extjs.

```
C:\Sencha\apps\HelloExt>sencha -sdk c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\apps\extjs\ext-4.2.1.883 generate app HelloExt .
```

It creates a app named HelloExt at C:\Sencha\apps\HelloExt location , but it created ext and build directories on C:\

because of this when i launch a sencha web start it gives me error for ext and build directory.

when i gone through the ExtJS documentation it says that this commnad should create the ext and build directory as well.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_app

i doubt if i am missing some configuration setting, help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the workspace.

i did not created the workspace anytime but i don't know how it got created and hence it was referring to the paths defined in workspace conf file.

I manually deleted the workspace directory and then i tried generating the app with the above command, now it created the proper directory structure as shown in sencha docs.

i used the following command to generate the app.

```
C:\Sencha\apps\HelloExt>sencha -sdk c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\apps\extjs\ext-4.2.1.883 generate app HelloExt .
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try using the whole path.

> C:\Sencha\apps>sencha -sdk c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\apps\extjs\ext-4.2.1.883 generate app HelloExt C:\Sencha\apps\HelloExt

Comment: I'm not sure it helps, but I always gave the directory name as explicit parameter instead of `.` only.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz but it does not solve the problem. rather i need to manually copy the ext directory from c:\ location to c:\sencha\apps\HelloExt directory.

Comment: Does `sencha app build` work afterwards ? If not you'd better find the issue.

Comment: I used absolute as well as relative path to the application directory but it does not help, i think the reason is it creates the source code(ext directory) at a common location rather than creating it for each application every time.

Comment: Are you using a workspace ? (Sencha generate workspace) If you use a workspace, this defines the common location of the library. If you don't use workspaces, every app has its own library in \MyApp\ext folder

Comment: Yes, i think the issue is regarding the workspace. i am not sure how this workspace got created , i never created the workspace anytime. now may be i'll need to google more regardidng deletion of workspace.